# Enter modal application state until the next click with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

After having limited success with drag&drop mainly because the sluggish and jumpy behavior of slow mobile devices, I want to implement a modal approach to moving an element from a to b like this:

1. User clicks on an item. The item is visually marked by setting a css class.
2. User clicks on a target item. The marked item is instantly moved to the target item.

Alternatively:

3. User clicks anywhere but on a target item: marked item is unmarked and nothing else happens.

So the idea is to enter a modal state in (1) and leave the modal state in the (2) or the (3) action.

I have no problem implementing (1) and (2). What I don't now is how to best implement (3). To what should I bind a general "anywhere else" click?

Comment: Listen clicks on the document.

Answer (score 0):

I too had run into this problem long back. So I came up with this (*hacky?*) solution.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c3o6a5xu/)**

Basically it uses a "proxy" div to simulate "anything but the content".

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="general_everywhere"></div>
    <div class="button">Button here</div>
    <div class="button">Button here</div>
    <div class="button">Button here</div>
    <div class="button">Button here</div>
    <div class="button">Button here</div>
    <div class="button">Button here</div>
    <div class="button">Button here</div>
    <div class="button">Button here</div>
    <div class="button">Button here</div>
    <div class="button">Button here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#general_everywhere
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    _background: blue;
    display: block;
}

.button
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #efefef;
}

.clicked
{
    background: red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});

$('#general_everywhere').click(function(){
    $('.button').removeClass('clicked');
    alert('You clicked on everywhere! You are GOD!');
});
```

Hope it helps.